# What can I do with a buried copper gas line?

Tags: gas

When we bought our house in 2005 we were advised by our utility company that there was a gas line on the property. We discovered it is at the bottom of an old BBQ grill that apparently didn't work and was turned into a planter, overflowing with ivy.

One day I came outside to find the grill/planter had fallen over exposing the brass or copper gas tubing.

What can I do with this now? It appears copper is no longer considered stable for gas so I suppose I can't use it for a fire pit.

Suggestions? i have sent an email to the utility company asking for advice. The copper is now bent because the planter fell.

Thanks in advance!

M

Comment: You should be able to trace the copper line back to your gas service line. Make sure it is shut off there. Is it connected there by one of those saddle valves which pierces the black iron service line just before it enters the structure?

Comment: I take it your local codes no longer permit copper for gas?

Answer (score 1):

In our neighborhood of 1970 built tract houses some homeowners added copper lines to a grill in back and a gas light front. The copper lines are invariably  connected to a saddle valve on the black iron gas service line above ground just before it enters the structure. (Fortunately no previous owner of our house added this.)

Some years back I helped a neighbor whose grill was non functional, dilapidated and whose gas light rusted out at the bottom and fell over. I made sure the saddle valve was off at the supply and I removed both the grill and the gas light. I cut off the copper lines below ground and flattened the copper tubing for 6" or so to seal it, then buried it. So there is 100 ft or more of abandoned copper tubing in the ground still connected to the gas service line.

Comment: Additionally I would have disconnected those gas lines at the source and capped the valve, then cut the disconnected line at the source making it too short to just hook back up.  Why?  It surprising what people will “try” when something’s not working.  Let’s pretend the neighbor moved and the next guy can’t figure out why the furnace won’t light, [he’s never seen a gas meter before](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/144595/cannot-shut-off-water-from-street-valve/144653) and decides maybe it’s these saddle valves... you get the idea.

Comment: @Tyson, is there an approved bolt-on seal to allow removal of the saddle valve to cover the hole in the "black iron" gas supply line from being pierced by the saddle valve? Or do you recommend just turning off the valve and capping it?

Comment: I don’t know how to seal holes from a saddle valve, I’d just shut the valve off and cap it.  (I’m not sure saddle valves can even be used with gas in my state—I’ve never seen it.)